# How to add html and css in public function?

Tags: php, html, css, public-method

This is my code:

```
  public function getName() {
      return trim(stripslashes(strtr($this->_firstName . ' ' . $this->_surname1 . ' --ID is: ' . $this->_surname2, $this->_trans)));
  }
```

output is like this. example: Alex Rodriguez --ID is: A-Rod

How to change **Alex** font to blue, **Rodriguez** to red, **A-Rod** to yellow and **--ID is:** to green color?

```html
<span style="color:#0000CD;">Alex</span> <span style="color:#FF0000;">Rodriguez</span> <span style="color:#008000;">--ID is:</span> <span style="color:#FFFF00;">A-Rod</span>
```

How can I add css or html into above code??

For example: How can I change font color to blue color, or how can I use style and html ...

Thank you so much.

Comment: You learn CSS, plain and simple.

Comment: How you can add css into that code?

Comment: http://www.csstutorial.net/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 things you can do. Write css in a separate file and just link it to your page ( or just put everything in a `style` tag) or you can write incline css for every element ( not recommended ). You might want to output your text into different elements (e.g. `span`)so you can easily manipulate it.

Your code could look something like :

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
.first-name{
    color : blue;
}

.surname{
    color : red;
}

.person-id{
    color : green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
//Rest of your PHP code
public function getName()
  {
  return trim(stripslashes(strtr('<span class="first-name">'.$this->_firstName. '</span><span class="surname">' . $this->_surname1 . '</span> --ID is: <span class="person-id">' . $this->_surname2.'</span>', $this->_trans)));
  }
//Rest of your PHP code
 ?>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Please do remember that PHP is a server side language and that the result your browser will actually get is :

```html
<html>
<head>
<style>
.first-name{
 color : blue;
}

.surname{
 color : red;
}

.person-id{
 color : green;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<span class="first-name">John</span><span class="surname">Smith</span> --ID is: <span class="person-id">John-S</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for how to use css class related to that public function.. thanks